# JQuery $('#image').addimagezoom, for pics dispersed from database

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a variable that displays pictures that reference a row in a database.

When I use the the Javascript for magnifyzoom:

```
 "$('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [300,300],
        magnifierpos: 'left',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: ''                "
    })
```

It will only zoom in on the first image.  And then when I change the hash mark with a period, switching ID to CLASS, it will zoom in on all the images but it will disperse one type of image.  If you need more information to help solve this riddle please let me know.

Comment: Yes, please provide more information.  I don't understand what "it will zoom in on all the images but it will disperse one type of image!" means.

Comment: it means that I put in the code: $('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
  zoomrange: [3, 10],
  magnifiersize: [300,300],
  magnifierpos: 'left',
  cursorshade: true,
  largeimage: '' 
 })

Comment: along with a .js page filled with code

Comment: and ..<img id="image1" src="${initParam.locationOfImage}${Image.ID}.jpg" 
                         style= "width:180px; height: 180px" 
                         alt="<fmt:message key='${Image.ID}'/>">

Comment: the magnify zoom effect only works on the first image due to it being an id as opposed to a class

Comment: when I switch it to a class it will do the magnify zoom effect on all photos but only one type of photo will show for all the different items,

Comment: for instance, I'll have the variable ${Item.ID} for the row in a database and it will show all items in from that row in the database

Comment: I have pictures that match up to the code and for some reason this javascript/ JQuery code makes a mess out of it.  It will only zoom in on one picture is referencing id=   or when I switch it to class= then it will work but only show one type of picture for all the items listed, for instance, it will show the picture for one gameboy game on all of the different gameboy games

Answer (score 0):

look like you need to use **largeimage** attribute in script.

```
$('.img').addimagezoom({
zoomrange: [6, 18],
magnifiersize: [600,600],
magnifierpos: 'right',
cursorshade: true,
cursorshadecolor: 'pink',
cursorshadeopacity: 0.3,
cursorshadeborder: '1px solid red',
    /*8888888 SEE HERE 8888888*/
largeimage: $(this).attr('src') //<-- No comma after last option!
})
```

Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6TMs/10/

Comment: Thank u graciously for not forgetting about me, I'll twiddlefiddle Dee with this in two shakes,,  I thank u.

Comment: if it solved your problem then just mark it as answer for reference to other people.

Comment: well I tried and the same problem keeps occuring, I need to somehow create a loop for the rest of the pictures that display from the database, oooh, you know what, I have an idea, let me try it and as soon as I get it, I'll post the code