# Change image in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a function to use a zoom on an image. I found the script that does what I want.

```
$('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
    zoomrange: [3, 10],
    magnifiersize: [300,300],
    magnifierpos: 'right',
    cursorshade: true,
    largeimage: 'hayden.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
})
```

What I would like to do is change the image using an onclick event. I can change the small image. Does anyone know if using this code it is possible to change the largeimage?

The code the script produces looks like this:

```
    <div class="magnifyarea featuredimagezoomerhidden" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px; left: 624px; top: 444.75px; visibility: visible; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid black; display: none;">
          <div style="position: relative; left: -393px; top: -231px; z-index: 0;">
              <img src="hayden.jpg" style="width: 945px; height: 531px;">
          </div>
     </div>
```

What I could do is to change the image here. I can use getElementsByClassName to change if I can access the div and them the image after. In CSS you can use

```
.this_table tr td
```

Can I something like that will getElementsByClassName?

Comment: What do you mean by _change the largeimage_?

Comment: I've got link with an onclick script which changes the small image but the large image is defined in the above script. Is there any way to change what that will be as the same time?

Comment: are you using a plugin for zoom ??

Comment: I think so. Do you need that? I was hoping there was an easy way to access the large image

Comment: With jQuery you can use the same selector-style as with CSS, so: `$('#image1 img')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15351848/3407923 might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
document.querySelector('.magnifyarea div img').src='large_img.jph'"
```

Are there likly to be any problems using this method?

Answer (score 0):

With some previous plug-ins that I have used I was able to do the following:

```
$('#image1').addimagezoom().largeimage = "myimagescr";
```

This may or may not work, but without the plug in, it's worth a try.

Comment: Would it help if I posted a link to the page where I found the script? That looked like it should work but it didn't.
Is there something special I need to do in the onclick to get it to run jQuery rather than JavaScript?